# jQuery accordion exclude expand/collapse event for a inner header element.

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <span>Unit 1</span>
        <i class="fi-pencil editWorkUnit" title="Edit work unit" unit="1"></i>
    </h3>
    <div>Unit 1 Details</div>
    <h3>
        <span>Unit 2</span>
        <i class="fi-pencil editWorkUnit" title="Edit work unit" unit="2"></i>
    </h3>
    <div>Unit 2 Details</div>
    <h3>
        <span>Unit 3</span>
        <i class="fi-pencil editWorkUnit" title="Edit work unit" unit="3"></i>
    </h3>
    <div>Unit 3 Details</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
       heightStyle: "content",
       collapsible: true
    });
});
```

This is working fine. When you click on accordion header it will expand/collapse their contents. If you see the HTML markup I have an edit icon inside each header `<h3>` tag. What I want is when user clicks on the icon I don't want to expand/collapse the accordion.

How to exclude the click event on that element inside a header.

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Ok, let me do that for you.

Comment: Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/qtc65de6/3/). Clicking on unit name should expand/collapse the accordion but clicking on edit link should not expand/collapse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop propagation on click for element `.editWorkUnit`

Check this code:

```
$('.editWorkUnit').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
})
.... your code
```

And codepen http://codepen.io/todorutandrei/pen/XKrZYG

Comment: It's not working. Clicking on edit link is opening/closing the accordion content.

Comment: or the problem could be that the icon element has width or height  equals 0 - check also this

Comment: can you give me a fiddle with the code - where you have included css/html/javascript

Comment: I see it's working on the codepan. I am generating all HTML via an ajax call. So I have to bind the click event with `.on` method. Can you please make this working with that. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/qtc65de6/5/) is the fiddle I tried. But it's not working.

Comment: I missed the h3 tag in onclick function ... https://jsfiddle.net/qtc65de6/9/ - so check this. This is not a problem for the functionality because you can change it and will work with accordion

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated the fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qtc65de6/8/)

you just have to add :

```
 $( ".editWorkUnit" ).on( "click",function(e) {
      .stopPropagation();
  });
```